# Hue with LDAP not working for some users (WebHdfsException at /)

Tags: hadoop, hue, mapr

Following the `mapr hadoop` [docs](https://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/Hue/ConfigureHuewithLDAP-AuthenticateUsers.html) for setting up `hue` with LDAP (direct bind, active directory method), restarting the services, and attempting to log into hue, some users get the following `Django error:

```
WebHdfsException at /
IOException: Error getting user info for current user, <someusername>(error 500)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://mapr004.myorg.local:8888/
Django Version: 1.6.10
Exception Type: WebHdfsException
Exception Value:    
IOException: Error getting user info for current user, <someusername>(error 500)
Exception Location: /opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.12.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/fs/webhdfs.py in _stats, line 265
Python Executable:  /opt/mapr/hue/hue-3.12.0/build/env/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.13
```

while others can log in fine. What is happening here and what can be done to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem to have fixed it.

Looking into the error message `WebHDFSException` and looking at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19043612/8236733) problems that raise this error, it seems like the problem is that Hue using LDAP looks for an existing user on the cluster (ie. a user in the cluster with the same name across all nodes (should have same uid and gid as well?)) and checks that there is such a 'cluster-user' who's name matches the name being used to login using the Hue LDAP auth.

Thus, I created a user myname (same name as my active directory name) across all nodes. After doing this, I was able to login to Hue using LDAP with my AD credentials.